# API response is inconsistant between end points - One throws an error while others return an expected 0 results

Tags: bug, api

I am looking at old posts via the API. There are three end points to do this:

- [/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers)
- [/posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts)
- [/questions](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions)

For my tests, I'm pulling back `body`, `body_markdown`, and the wrapper (with `total` included).

---

If I attempt to pull all **answers** from June 9, 2008 to June 10, 2008 (SO launched in August 2008) I get an expected result of 0 items.

Demo Link: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#fromdate=2008-06-09&todate=2008-06-10&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!%29Q29lpdRHRpjEiih5WDQWLpD&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Response:

```
{
  "items": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9985,
  "total": 0
}
```

---

If I do a test with **posts** (both answers and questions), I get a similar response

Demo Link (I made this a code block, because the asterisk in the filter breaks the URL link from forming properly): `https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts#pagesize=100&fromdate=2008-06-09&todate=2008-06-10&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!LH22RLun11EAAQcDbFY*%28S&site=stackoverflow&run=true`

Response:

```
{
  "items": [],
  "has_more": false,
  "quota_max": 10000,
  "quota_remaining": 9965,
  "total": 0
}
```

---

A similar test of the **questions** end point throws an **internal error**:

Demo Link: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#fromdate=2008-06-09&todate=2008-06-10&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=!-MOiNm40GCvjDwbu55-kFZzlg894gCxNx&site=stackoverflow&run=true

```
{
  "error_id": 500,
  "backoff": 10,
  "error_message": "this error has been logged",
  "error_name": "internal_error"
}
```

---

Can the `/questions` endpoint be fixed to return 0 results instead of throwing an `internal_error`?

Comment: That's definitely not the intended behaviour. FWIW, querying /questions actually does fail internally - the query backing that endpoint is timing out for some reason.

Comment: Is backoff standard with an internal error? (also nice way to check my backoff code works :P)

Comment: This also appears to be specific to `site=stackoverflow`.